# Open a file image in Python, store as a variable, display the image to Python program, perform an analysis of the image with Facial Recognition

Tags: python, opencv, azure-cognitive-services

I am trying to create a file explorer in Python that allows me to pull an image file from any directory on a windows system.  So far, I have been unable to accomplish this seemingly basic task in Python.  Even the professors at my school are unable to assist.

The program I'm attempting to make will be performing Facial Recognition on an image file, storing the image file as a variable, then performing the analysis of that file and printing the analysis to some tkinter labels.

I have bitten off more than I can chew currently. I'm a new programmer, I've been programming for about 3 months.  I'm in an Artificial Intelligence class, however, the class uses no structured language.  It seems there are no expert python programmers in our school, so I could definitely use some help.

Any recommendations for GUI tools and Facial Recognition would be greatly appreciated.  The previous API used was the cognitive_face API from microsoft Azure.  Looking for a free opensource API that is as effective as cognitive_face.

Here is some basic code below.  Looking for any recommendations available.

```
import subprocess
from tkinter import *



#Define Functions Here
def Open_File():
    subprocess.Popen(r'explorer /select,"C:\path\of\folder\file"')

def main_window(main):
    window.title('Facial Recognition')
    main.update_idletasks()
    width = 1024
    height = 768
    #find the center point of the width on the screen
    x = (main.winfo_screenwidth()//2)-(width//2)
    #find the center point of the height on the screen
    y = (main.winfo_screenheight()//2)-(height//2)

    main.geometry('{}x{}+{}+{}'.format(width,height,x,y))



#Define your Window
window = Tk()
main_window(window)

#Create Frames
topFrame = Frame(window)
topFrame.pack(side=LEFT)
bottomFrame = Frame(window)
bottomFrame.pack(side=RIGHT)

#Add Cascade Dropdown Menus
menu = Menu(window) #Add a Menu to the main window
window.config(menu=menu)

subMenu=Menu(menu)#declare a subMenu for menu
menu.add_cascade(label="File",menu=subMenu)#assign a dropdown for menu
subMenu.add_command(label="Open Image..",command =Open_File)
#Add a separator for your subMenu
subMenu.add_separator()
subMenu.add_command(label="Exit",command=exit)


#Add Buttons
##button1 = Button(topFrame,text="Open File...",fg="Grey",command=Open_File)
##button1.pack()
##button2 = Button(topFrame,text="Open Image...",fg="Dark Grey")
##button2.pack()


#Official Window loop continuously displays to screen
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: I think you're looking for tkinter's askopenfile functions. https://pythonspot.com/tk-file-dialogs/

Answer (score 0):

This should get you to where you can pass the file to OpenCV

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

class Application(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):

        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):

        menubar = Menu(root)

        #SETUP FILE MENU
        filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.quit)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)

        selectmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        selectmenu.add_command(label="Select Images", command= self.Find_Face)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="Select Images", menu=selectmenu)

        root.config(menu=menubar)

    #Define Functions Here
    def Open_File(self):
        self.filename =  filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/",title = "Select file",filetypes = (("jpeg files","*.jpg"),("all files","*.*")))
        return self.filename

    #Call open file from a different function and get the returned value
    def Find_Face(self):
        self.imagename = self.Open_File()
        print("File is: ", self.imagename)
        ##PASS THE FILE TO OPENCV AND PROCESS


#Official Window loop continuously displays to screen
root = Tk()
root.title("Facial Recognition")
root.geometry("1024x768")
app = Application(root)
root.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)
root.mainloop()
```

I've used tkinter a lot. This constructor is the easiest to build with. I modified it a bit to show how you can call the open file function from any other function and just get the returned value to pass onto whatever processing you want to do.

Here is what looks like a very simple to use python facial recognition: 
https://realpython.com/blog/python/face-recognition-with-python/

Comment: This is worlds beyond where I was at.  Thank you so much.  I've been trying to get this figured out for about two weeks.  I was surprised it was as difficult to find as it has been.

Comment: There is a youtube series on tkinter that is really good. Where I learned it.